# Evaluate a limit with exponential

Tags: calculus

Evaluate the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{\exp\left(\frac{-1}{(x-2)(4-x)}\right)}{x-2}$$

I know that this limit must be zero, but I'm having a hard time arriving at it. So far, I have tried making a substitution for $\frac{1}{x-2}$, but I still am left with the 4-x, which I am not sure what to do with.

Comment: I have tried making a substitution for 1/(x-2)

Comment: You may include this comment to the body of your question to show what you've tried.

Comment: If you choose to substitute, you definitely need to substitute in for all the x, so the whole expression is in terms of y. Are you able to do that?

Comment: If I do substitute for 1/(x-2)(4-x), then I get e^(-y) in the numerator, but I'm having trouble with the denominator.

Comment: The limits from the right and left are not equal.

Comment: Why do you say the right and left limits are not equal?

Comment: @Charles: Let $x$ be a tiny bit below $2$. Then $-\frac{1}{(x-2)(4-x)}$ is large **positive**.  So the $\exp$ of it is very large positive.  The denominator $x-2$ is small negative. So the ratio is very large negative.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to 2^+}\frac{\exp\left(\frac{-1}{(x-2)(4-x)}\right)}{x-2}$$
$u = \frac{1}{x-2},\qquad x = \frac{1+2u}{u}$ 
$$=\lim_{u\to \infty^+} u\exp\left(\frac{u^2}{1-2u}\right)$$
$v = \frac{u^2}{1-2u},\qquad u = \sqrt{v^2+v}-v$
$$=\lim_{v\to \infty^-} e^v\sqrt{v^2+v}-\lim_{v\to \infty^-}ve^v$$
$$=\sqrt{\lim_{v\to \infty^-}\frac{v^2+v}{e^{-2v}}}-\lim_{v\to \infty^-}\frac{v}{e^{-v}}$$
$$=\lim_{v\to \infty^-}\frac{1}{e^{-v}} + \sqrt{-\lim_{v\to \infty^-}\frac{v+1}{e^{-2v}}} $$
$$=\sqrt{\lim_{v\to \infty^-}\frac{1}{2e^{-2v}}} $$
$$=\sqrt{0}$$
$$=\color{red}{0}$$
Approaching the limit from the other direction yields divergence, so the two sided limit does not exist. This exercise is left to the OP.